# error: LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get details about installed applications in my post. And, I'm getting the below errors:

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

#ifdef _UNICODE
#define tcout       wcout
#define tstring     wstring
#else
#define tcout       cout
#define tstring     string
#endif

tstring RegistryQueryValue(HKEY hKey,
    LPCTSTR szName)
{
    tstring value;

    DWORD dwType;
    DWORD dwSize = 0;

    if (::RegQueryValueEx(
        hKey,                   // key handle
        szName,                 // item name
        NULL,                   // reserved
        &dwType,                // type of data stored
        NULL,                   // no data buffer
        &dwSize                 // required buffer size
        ) == ERROR_SUCCESS && dwSize > 0)
    {
        value.resize(dwSize);

        ::RegQueryValueEx(
            hKey,                   // key handle
            szName,                 // item name
            NULL,                   // reserved
            &dwType,                // type of data stored
            (LPBYTE)&value[0],      // data buffer
            &dwSize                 // available buffer size
            );
    }

    return value;
}

void RegistryEnum()
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG ret = ::RegOpenKeyEx(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,     // local machine hive
        __TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"), // uninstall key
        0,                      // reserved
        KEY_READ,               // desired access
        &hKey                   // handle to the open key
        );

    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return;

    DWORD dwIndex = 0;
    DWORD cbName = 1024;
    TCHAR szSubKeyName[1024];

    while ((ret = ::RegEnumKeyEx(
        hKey,
        dwIndex,
        szSubKeyName,
        &cbName,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL)) != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            HKEY hItem;
            if (::RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, szSubKeyName, 0, KEY_READ, &hItem) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                continue;

            tstring name = RegistryQueryValue(hItem, __TEXT("DisplayName"));
            tstring publisher = RegistryQueryValue(hItem, __TEXT("Publisher"));
            tstring version = RegistryQueryValue(hItem, __TEXT("DisplayVersion"));
            tstring location = RegistryQueryValue(hItem, __TEXT("InstallLocation"));

            if (!name.empty())
            {
                tcout << name << endl;
                tcout << "  - " << publisher << endl;
                tcout << "  - " << version << endl;
                tcout << "  - " << location << endl;
                tcout << endl;
            }

            ::RegCloseKey(hItem);
        }
        dwIndex++;
        cbName = 1024;
    }
    ::RegCloseKey(hKey);
}

void main(){
    RegistryEnum();
}
```

Errors:

> LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
>
> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_RegCloseKey@4 referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl RegistryEnum(void)" (?RegistryEnum@@YAXXZ)
>
> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_RegEnumKeyExW@32 referenced
>   in function "void __cdecl RegistryEnum(void)" (?RegistryEnum@@YAXXZ)
>
> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_RegOpenKeyExW@20 referenced
>   in function "void __cdecl RegistryEnum(void)" (?RegistryEnum@@YAXXZ)
>
> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **imp__RegQueryValueExW@24
>   referenced in function "class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl
>   RegistryQueryValue(struct HKEY** *,wchar_t const *)"
>   (?RegistryQueryValue@@YA?AV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@*W@2@@std@@PAUHKEY*_@@PB_W@Z)
>
> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *wWinMain@16 referenced in
>   function _*_tmainCRTStartup

How may I fix this please?

Comment: They are Linking related errors. Add Advapi32.lib in Additional dependancy tab (or whatever they name it nowadays). Errors say that IDE cannot find the *library* with functions mentioned.

Comment: I've tried to add it like this, `#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")`

Comment: Okay. It builds fine in VC++2010. Nothing fancy.

Comment: @SChepurin, is this coming from VS2013? Libraries linking?

Comment: Nothing else. IDE cannot find the Advapi32.lib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must link with the `Advapi32.lib`.

Comment: Your code looks OK, what programming environnment do you use ?

Comment: Visua Studio 2013 Ultimate