# fetching windows current user with java native interfaces

Tags: java, c++, winapi, java-native-interface

I am trying to make a proof of concept where in a cpp program I fetch the windows username and then call this program from a java code, using Java native interface(JNI). Now what i have so far is, a sample JNI hello world program which is able to compile and print Hello world or what what ever parameter I set up. Now in a separate cpp snippet i am able to fetch the current username and it works as well; looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char acUserName[100];
    DWORD nUserName = sizeof(acUserName);
    if (GetUserName(acUserName, &nUserName)) {
        cout << "User name is " << acUserName << "." << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and executed using my G++ in command prompt it prints the current username correctly.

Now i just want to combine the two programs. When I do that as follows

```
public class Sample1
 {
    public native String fetchCurrentUserName();
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     System.loadLibrary("Sample1");
     Sample1 sample = new Sample1();     
     String  userName   = sample.fetchCurrentUserName();       
     System.out.println("userName: " + userName);
     
    }
 }
```

This is the java part and the cpp part is as follows:

```
 #include "Sample1.h"
 #include <string.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <windows.h>
 using namespace std;


  JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Sample1_fetchCurrentUserName
   (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    char acUserName[100];
    DWORD nUserName = sizeof(acUserName);
    if (GetUserName(acUserName, &nUserName)) {
        cout << "User name is " << acUserName << "." << endl;
        cin.get();
    }

    const char* userName = acUserName;
    //const char* userName = "acUserName";
    return env->NewStringUTF(userName);
 }
 
 void main(){}
```

This does not compile anymore, it says

```
Sample1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetUserNameA referenced in function Java_Sample1_fetchCurrentUserName
Sample1.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I used the following command to compile the JNI code.

cl -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\include\win32" -LD Sample1.cpp -FeSample1.dll

as per tutorial from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html. Now from few other questions in stack overflow it seems somehow my program is unable to link the windows library or leader somehow. But I have no clue as to how this can be solved. Any body have any bright ideas? Please make my day! Thank you for your time :D I looked into [Linking of dll file in JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904957/linking-of-dll-file-in-jni) which is very relevant for my question. But not sure if the solutions are applicable to me.

#### Edit

[error: LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757314/error-lnk1120-5-unresolved-externals) This question had similar problem and it seems to have same solution which is as suggested by Remy to link with Advapi32.lib. At least now i learned few new things like #pragma comments and the role of Advapi32 library. Many thanks!

Comment: Your C++ code needs to link to `Advapi32.lib`, either through a linker parameter in the project options, or via a `#pragma comment(lib)` statement in the C++ code itself. Otherwise, you can use the Win32 API `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` functions to get a pointer to `GetUserNameA()` directly from `Advapi32.dll` at runtime instead of linking to `Advapi32.lib` at compile-time

Comment: On the other hand, why use `GetUserName()` in C++ at all? Java has its own access to the username: [Get login username in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797549/)

Comment: I have seen this solution in other question. However i myself have no idea what this Advapi32.lib does. Could you please tell me why is this important in my case and where do i look to get the exact command/code to perform the task. I am super noob in cpp and JNI both sorry. :(

Comment: This has nothing to do with JNI. It is how C++ compilers\linkers work in general. `Advapi32.lib` is the import library for `Advapi32.dll`, it tells the linker which functions are exported from the DLL and how.  The linker uses import libs to resolve DLL function calls made by the C++ code.

Comment: This is a proof of concept in order to learn about java native api, later on I need to fetch SID and something to do with native api. Not yet there. So I need to do this in cpp only. But thank you for the link as well :D

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation on Advapi32.lib role. I will try to find a way to link it now.

Comment: Ok @RemyLebeau I just added #pragma comment(lib,"advapi32.lib") line in my cpp and it compiled fine, just as you suggested. Your solution works great. May I request you to answer that so that I can officially accept it. Many thanks sir.

Comment: I posted a more detailed answer for you

Comment: You can get a lot of user information via JAAS: see [`com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/NTSystem.html).

Comment: ok @EJP I will look into JAAS. It seems it has lot of user SID etc meaningful information for me, in the first look itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code **compiles** fine.  You are actually getting a **linker** error, not a **compiler** error.

From the error message, you can see that your C++ code is trying to call a  `GetUserNameA()` function.  `GetUserName()` is a preprocessor `#define` macro in `winbase.h` (which is included by `windows.h`) that resolves to `GetUserNameA()` when `UNICODE` is not defined:

```
WINADVAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
GetUserNameA (
    __out_ecount_part_opt(*pcbBuffer, *pcbBuffer) LPSTR lpBuffer,
    __inout LPDWORD pcbBuffer
    );
WINADVAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
GetUserNameW (
    __out_ecount_part_opt(*pcbBuffer, *pcbBuffer) LPWSTR lpBuffer,
    __inout LPDWORD pcbBuffer
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetUserName  GetUserNameW
#else
#define GetUserName  GetUserNameA // <-- HERE!
#endif // !UNICODE
```

As there is no `GetUserNameA()` function implemented in your C++ code, but there is at least a declaration available (from `winbase.h`), the compiler emits machine code that references `GetUserNameA()` externally (via a symbol named `__imp_GetUserNameA`).  When the linker is then invoked after compiling is finished, the linker outputs the "unresolved" error because it is not able to find an implementation of any `GetUserNameA` function to satisfy that reference.

`GetUserNameA()` is a Win32 API function implemented in `Advapi32.dll`.  You need to link to `Advapi32.lib` from your compiler's Windows SDK so the linker can find the implementation of `GetUserNameA()`.

One way to do that is to add a `#pragma comment(lib)` statement to your C++ code, eg:

```
#include "Sample1.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib") // <-- add this!

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Sample1_fetchCurrentUserName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    char acUserName[100] = {};
    DWORD nUserName = sizeof(acUserName);
    if (GetUserNameA(acUserName, &nUserName)) {
        cout << "User name is " << acUserName << "." << endl;
    }
    else {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        cout << "Unable to get User name, error " << dwErr << "." << endl;
    }

    return env->NewStringUTF(acUserName);
}

void main() {}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include "Sample1.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Sample1_fetchCurrentUserName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    DWORD nUserName = 100, dwErr;
    std::vector<char> acUserName(nUserName);
    do {
        if (GetUserNameA(&acUserName[0], &nUserName)) {
            cout << "User name is " << &acUserName[0] << "." << endl;
            break;
        }
        dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            cout << "Unable to get the User name, error " << dwErr << "." << endl;
            break;
        }
        acUserName.resize(nUserName);
    }
    while (true);

    return env->NewStringUTF(&acUserName[0]);
}

void main() {}
```

That being said, `NewStringUTF()` requires an input string in [**modified** UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8) format.  However, `GetUserNameA()` outputs ANSI format (hence the `A` in its name), not in UTF-8, let alone *modified* UTF-8.  Windows has no concept of *modified* UTF-8 at all.  Your code will work correctly only if the username does not contain any non-ASCII characters in it.

Your C++ code really should be calling `GetUserNameW()` instead, which outputs in UTF-16 format.  Then you can use `NewString()` instead of `NewStringUTF()` (Java strings use UTF-16 anyway), eg:

```
#include "Sample1.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Sample1_fetchCurrentUserName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    WCHAR acUserName[100];
    DWORD nUserName = 100;
    if (GetUserNameW(acUserName, &nUserName)) {
        --nUserName; // ignore the null terminator
        wcout << L"User name is " << acUserName << L"." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        nUserName = 0;
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        cout << "Unable to get the User name, error " << dwErr << "." << endl;
    }

    return env->NewString(reinterpret_cast<jchar*>(acUserName), nUserName);
}

void main() {}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include "Sample1.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Sample1_fetchCurrentUserName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    DWORD nUserName = 100, dwErr;
    std::vector<WCHAR> acUserName(nUserName);
    do {
        if (GetUserNameW(&acUserName[0], &nUserName)) {
            --nUserName; // ignore the null terminator
            wcout << L"User name is " << &acUserName[0] << L"." << endl;
            break;
        }
        dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            nUserName = 0;
            cout << "Unable to get the User name, error " << dwErr << "." << endl;
            break;
        }
        acUserName.resize(nUserName);
    }
    while (true);

    return env->NewString(reinterpret_cast<jchar*>(&acUserName[0]), nUserName);
}

void main() {}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.